# Exported apk file has bug not present when downloaded to phone using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I have an application using google maps which works perfectly when run on a real device (Samsung Fame) using eclipse. When I export the same file to publish it on Google Play the same app will not launch a google map showing a particular location to the user.
I have tested the apk file generated in the bin folder within the workspace on three real devices and the map functionality works perfectly. The supposedly same exported apk file using eclipse, tested on the same three devices does not launch the map when selected.
Any suggestions as to why the exported apk file behaves differently to the one in the bin folder ?

Comment: The file in your bin/ folder is probaby a debug build.  On an exported release build there are two changes - you go through proguard, which can obfuscate names that need to remain unchanged to interact with components in ways proguard can't envision, and you change certificates, to one that might not match your maps api key.  You should be able to tell which by examining the logcat output of the run attempt (collect it using logcat in the shell). Post the logcat by editing it into your question if you can't find the problem on your own.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the help. I was using a API key based on a debug certificate rather than a release certificate. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch from a debug build to a release build, your signing certificate necessarily changes.

The Google Maps API key is tied to your signing certificate, so you must use an API key which matches your release certificate.